# gremlin: limit step vs take step

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin

I am new to gremlin and while referring to [this](http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=13224) website, I came across `take()` step. It has the same output as `limit()` which makes me wonder what is the difference between the two. I am unable to find any clarification regarding this matter. Thanks!

Comment: While the `limit()` step is part of the documentation - http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#limit-step I did not find the `take()` step

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately that's a bit confusing. `take()` is not a Gremlin step. It is instead a Groovy function that is being applied to the end of a traversal (which itself is an `Iterator`). In much the same way that you can use `take()` at then end of a traversal you can use other Groovy functions:

```
gremlin> g.V().take(1)
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.V().collect{it.value('name')}
==>marko
==>vadas
==>lop
==>josh
==>ripple
==>peter
```

Of course, once you use a Groovy function to process the pipeline you can't go back to Gremlin steps:

```
gremlin> g.V().take(1).out()
No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods$TakeIterator.out() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: sum(), sort(), sort(groovy.lang.Closure), sort(java.util.Comparator), count(java.lang.Object), count(groovy.lang.Closure)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
```

which is why you would prefer `limit(1)`:

```
gremlin> g.V().limit(1).out()
==>v[3]
==>v[2]
==>v[4]
```

Of course, if you're not using Groovy and are programming in a Java environment then it would be obvious that `take()` and other such functions aren't going to be available to you.

Comment: This was indeed useful! Thank you Stephen

Answer (score 0):

The `limit()` step should be used and is, as of TinkerPop 3.4, the canonical way to iterate a `Traversal` and retrieve the first `n` elements.

I can't remember why `take()` was available on `Traversal` instances at the time of writing of this article. This sounds a bit odd to me; it could be an `Iterator` (or comparable) interface leaking, but I'll let maintainers comment on this if they read this question.

You'll be safe with `limit()`.

Comment: Woops, race condition. Stephen's answer is obviously more complete :-).